# Proving properties of a function upon repeated iteration

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For an $n$-tuple $S$ of decreasing positive integers, we can define $f(S)$ as subtracting $1$ from every element of $S$, prepending $n$, and then removing $0$s and re-ordering in decreasing order if neccecary. For example, $f((4,2,1))=(3,3,1)$.

I've proven that repeated iteration of this function always ends at a cycle, by noticing that $f$, $f(f(x))$, etc. is a finite sequence. Now how can I prove that every tuple with the same sum will eventually go to the same cycle? I've verified that this is true with Mathematica.

EDIT: I'm looking to either prove or disprove this statement. I've verified it for a lot of cases, but it may not be true. This wasn't given as an assignment so I have no idea whether it's true.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you take $(n_1,n_2,...,n_m)\rightarrow (n_1-1,n_2-1,...,n_m-1)\rightarrow (m,n_1-1,n_2-1,...,n_m-1)$ and then you remove zeros?

Comment: @Yanko Correct. And I'll edit tags.

Comment: If we take any sequence $S=\{s_1...s_n\}$ then replace it with $\overline S=(\overline{s}=\max{\{m\}\cup S},\overline{s}-1,\overline{s}-2\ldots,1)$ then am I right in thinking the stopping time of the original $S$ is less than or equal to the stopping time of $\overline S$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be your initial $n$-tuple of decreasing integers. If $N := \sum_{x\in S} x$, note that $S$ describes a partition of $N$ (any partition of a positive integer can be written uniquely as a weakly decreasing sequence of numbers). Furthermore, $f$ is defined such that $f(S)$ is also a partition of $N$. Since there are only finitely many partitions of a given positive integer, the sequence $\{f^{k}(S)\}$ must eventually repeat.

**Edit:** However, the claim that there is only one cycle for each $N$ is *false*. For example, note that when $N = 17$, the partitions $(6,5,3,2,1)$ and $(6,4,4,2,1)$ are contained in disjoint cycles under the action of $f$.

Comment: Wait, but even if we know the sequence eventually repeats, how do we know it always repeats in the same way for the same $N$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread what you were asking. Let me think on it some more.